# WP8.1 How can i bind property in the visual state manager of a toggle button style

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I've decided to custom a toggle button with a custom style : it contains an image and text. 
The normal state of my button uses a specific image and a specific text foreground. 
the checked state uses other ones.

However... the switch doesn't work for my images.

I've created a custom toggle button. The code is right here :

```
class CustomToggleButton : ToggleButton
{

    public String ImageSource
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(String), typeof(CustomToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));



    public String SelectedImageSource
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(SelectedImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedImageSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedImageSource", typeof(String), typeof(CustomToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));


}
```

I use my control like this :

```
<controls:CustomToggleButton ImageSource="/Resources/home.png" SelectedImageSource="/Resources/home-neg.png" FontSize="18"
                             Content="Acceuil" Style="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuItemStyle}"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Here the custom toggle button style :

```
<x:Double x:Key="TextStyleLargeFontSize">18.14</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneButtonContentPadding">9.5,0,9.5,3.5</Thickness>
    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinHeight">57.5</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinWidth">109</x:Double>
    <Style x:Key="HamburgerMenuItemStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StandardFont}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonContentPadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:CustomToggleButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource IaF-SColor-DarkGreen}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource IaF-SColor-DarkGreen}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding SelectedImageSource}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="EnabledBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{ThemeResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentPresenter AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image x:Name="ToggleImage" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="EnabledContent" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                               FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                               TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

As you can see, i try to set my custom toggle button properties for two different states :

Normal state :

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleImage">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

And Checked state :

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="ToggleImage">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding SelectedImageSource}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

And... it doesn't work at all.

**EDIT :**

For the interested fellows, my solution is available bellow.

Comment: Did you try TemplateBinding?

Comment: Try this {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  TemplateParent},Path=ImageSource}

Comment: First solution just doesn't work, and the second one crashes my app !

Comment: Can you tell me the exception?

Comment: It crashs in "App.g.i.cs " with this message : 
 test.exe!test.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__2(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 50 C#

I think XAML doen't like the way we try to bind data.

Comment: See the answer. It's not possible yo do in visual states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764747/data-binding-property-of-a-other-control-to-a-style-while-animating-it) it's not possible.
You can't use dynamic resource 
references or data binding expressions to set Storyboard or animation property values. That's because everything inside a ControlTemplate must be thread-safe, and the timing system must Freeze Storyboard objects to make them thread-safe. A Storyboard cannot be frozen if it or its child timelines contain dynamic resource references or data binding expressions

Answer (score 1):

Its better to have overlapping images, and change the visibility of the images depending upon the state of the toggle button

Comment: indeed, it could be a solution. However, i wonder whether it's possible to do the trick in the visual state manager.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, my solution is bit different from the initial idea : I have integrated an additional image to manage the "selected state". Then, i play with the image visibility attribute in the visual state manager.

I've had an additional property on custom toggle button class to set the "selected image source"

```
public class CustomToggleButton : ToggleButton
{

    [...]

    public String SelectedImageSource
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(SelectedImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedImageSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedImageSource", typeof(String), typeof(CustomToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));


}
```

Then i've modified the call to this custom control :

```
<controls:CustomToggleButton ImageSource="/Resources/home.png" SelectedImageSource="/Resources/home-neg.png" FontSize="18" Click="CustomToggleButton_Click"
                             Content="Acceuil" Style="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuItemStyle}"   
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Finally, i've modified the custom toggle button style by setting another image, "SelectedItemImage", and i've used the visibility attribute to hide or show the right image.

```
<Style x:Key="HamburgerMenuItemStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StandardFont}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:CustomToggleButton" >
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemTextBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource IaF-SColor-DarkGreen}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedItemImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource IaF-SColor-DarkGreen}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemTextBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedItemImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ItemBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <ContentPresenter AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image x:Name="ItemImage" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="SelectedItemImage" Source="{Binding Path=SelectedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ItemTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                               FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                               TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Main changes are right here :

```
<Image x:Name="ItemImage" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}"/>
<Image x:Name="SelectedItemImage" Source="{Binding Path=SelectedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource MenuButtonImageSize}"/>
```

We bind source to the custom class dependency properties (thanks to Archana suggestion), and then we play with visibility in visual state manager, like this :

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedItemImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Are the images static? If yes, there's an easy way having the images in the style of the control and toggling visibility of the images in the visual states of the control. Else, dependency property is the way.

Comment: What do you mean by "static image" ?  I have a folder of images and i use my toggle button a multiple times with different image sets.

Comment: For example, toggle buttons are used for bool usecases like yes-no true-false. So by static images I meant, like a tick-cross image toggling. Wherein there is the same for one value. Tick image for a yes and cross image for no.